# Dlang LLVM ERROR: Program used external function which could not be resolved

Tags: c, llvm, cross-compiling, d, ldc

main.d

```
import std.stdio;

void    main()
{
    writeln("Hello World !!!");
}
```

when i compile and execute it is work perfectly

But when i try

```
ldc2 -output-ll main.d
lli main.ll

LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_d_throw_exception' which could not be resolved!
```

I try in c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void    main()
{
  printf("Hello World !!!");
}
```

and

```
clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c

lli foo.ll
```

it is work !!

Why in Dlang does not work when i compile width ldc ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the cruntime is avilable to lli.
Whereas the druntime is not.
If you were to link the druntime and phobos into lli or load it at startup it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ldc2 -output-ll -betterC main.d

    lli -load /usr/lib/libphobos2-ldc.so.72 main.ll

    ./main
```

output -> Hello World !!!

It is because

I need to disable all the functionality requiring runtime

http://forum.dlang.org/post/pqujluaxxmtfnoofqkje@forum.dlang.org
Thanks every one and David Nadlinger

Answer (score 0):

> LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_d_throw_exception' which could not be resolved!

You need to figure out which dynamic library has this symbol and link it dynamically to your program using `lli -load /path/to/your/library.{so,dylib} ... foo.ll`.

I am not a D developer so I don't what library you need. To find a library look at your Dlang distrubution's libraries. As Stefan K said it you probably need a library responsible for D runtime.

---

Generally if you are missing any symbols, on Linux system you can use

```
readelf --syms somelib.so
```

or

```
objdump --dynamic-syms somelib.so
```

Based on this command you can write a routine using `find` that will traverse through the folder with libraries you suspect to have the symbols you are missing, smth like:

```
find path-to-dlang-libs-folder -type f ! -name "*.so" -exec objcdump --dynamic-libs -- {} + | grep _start___minfo
```

You might need to tweak this command to work on Linux though.

Comment: lli -load /usr/lib/libdruntime-ldc-debug.so.72 -load /usr/lib/libphobos2-ldc-debug.so.72 main.ll

no work :(

i forgot something ?

LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__start___minfo' which could not be resolved!

Comment: Which operating system do you have?

Comment: Linux unknown 4.11.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 28 10:40:17 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Barre_k, I have updated my answer with more details. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lli -load /usr/lib/libdruntime-ldc-debug.so.72 -load /usr/lib/libphobos2-ldc-debug.so.72 main.ll
```

and i have

LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__start___minfo' which could not be resolved!